# UITableVIewCell , show edit contact button on swipe

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

How do I get the edit contact button to show when swiping on a UITableViewCell? The event is never raised and the edit button never appears.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 & iOS 11+

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    // since the style is destructive, so it will have a red background by default.
    // change it to .normal and it will have a blue background by default..
    let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Edit Contact") { _, _, complete in
        // continue your logic..
        // write your code to move to next screen.. Perform segue or move using storyboards..
        complete(true)
    }
    // if you want to add icon, then you can do it this way..
    editAction.image = UIImage(named: "editContact")
    // you can set your own background color for the button like this..
    editAction.backgroundColor = .orange
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [editAction])
    //set to false to prevent a full swipe from performing the first action..
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
    return configuration
}
```

Comment: Also I want to add NavigationVC for Edit Contact VC and wanna link it with my EditContact Swipe Button in TableViewCell @naveedulhassan5

Comment: I wanna navigate from Contacts Screen to Edit Contacts Screen Using that Swipe EditContact Button , thats what i want

Comment: //I am trying to present a viewController depending on which tableView cell is clicked.
//Currently if they are all clicked they redirect to the same viewController, how would I alter this?
extension SettingsVC: TableViewNew {
    func onClickCell(index: Int) {
      let aboutusVC = AboutUsVC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutusVC, animated: true)
        let tncVc = TermsAndConditionsVC()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tncVc, animated: true)
    }
    
}